# How many complete triangulations of the sphere are there in which every vertex has exactly degree five?

Tags: graph-theory

I know of one with 12 vertices, 20 faces, and 30 edges.  Are there any others? Almost sorry I asked the question.  The answer is trivial.  Use Euler's formula and the unique solution pops out.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v,e,f$ be the number of vertices, edges and faces. So by your given condition, we have $ e = 5v/2 , f = 5v/3   $. And use this in the euler characteristic formula for sphere $ v-e+f =2$ to get $v (1-5/2+5/3) = 2 \implies v = 12 $. So there are only one such triangulation.

Comment: Is it possible that there would be two non-isomorphic triangulations with the same number of vertices, edges, and faces?  No of course, but is there an easy way of seeing this?

Comment: I think it is possible that two non-isomorphic graph has same v, e, f. But I do not know the details.